# Wrapping a vector image around a compound path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm pretty newbish to vector art, so please bare with me.

I made a heart shape using compound paths. I also have vector image in a flame pattern. I want to wrap/distort/whatever the flame pattern to the heart. The idea is pretty straightforward - a heart wreathed in flames.

Here's a rough idea of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

[Source: Vectorstock](https://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/symbol-of-burning-heart-with-vector-7409284)

Here's where I am so far. Using flame vector art I found online, I made an art brush and applied it to the compound path of the heart. 
I like it, but I want the flames to originate on the center bottom of the heart, crawling up the outside edges of the heart.
my flaming heart

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Post a sketch or some visual aid to describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: @happi
Here's a rough idea of what I'm trying to do. [flaming heart](https://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/symbol-of-burning-heart-with-vector-7409284)

Here's where I am so far. Using flame vector art I found online, I made an art brush and applied it to the compound path of the heart. 
I like it, but I want the flames to originate on the center bottom of the heart, crawling up the outside edges of the heart.
[my flaming heart](http://www.ajack.io/flaming_heart_2.gif)

Comment: It would be much easier to draw the flames than to distort some you have found elsewhere. Those shapes are fairly simple.  Learn to use the Pen Tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no easy solution here other than draw/edit the flames to the shape you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the effect you want first draw your flames (or acquire them from a free vector image resource). Then draw your heart.

The action you seem to be hinting at is subtracting the heart from the flames ?

Here is a (very) quick example using some free flames from freepik.com

Practice using the pen tool and also the pathfinder which I use in this video to draw the heart then subtract the foreground heart from the background flames.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AN6Wk_mM-8

[image: Quick Example]